# Python exe file 0xc000007b error, Process monitor log available

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

I imported the file into a single exe file using nuitka and first when I ran the application I was getting api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll error and I installed the dll, now when I run it I get error 0xc000007b. When I run the project from main.py, it opens, but the exe file does not work.

```
Process Monitor Log File: https://www.mediafire.com/file/0fs9lr9rl0a8f4w/Logfile.PML/file
```

I deleted and reinstalled vcredist, .net framework and directx, but it didn't work.